# Azure Data Factory Pipeline hangs/timeouts

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I'm building a Data-warehouse, I'm extracting data from 2 source systems (A & B), the main pipeline is executing them in parallel, the 2 system are independent:

[image]

The extraction is being done via a set of queries that are stored in the DB in a table and being read by each of the pipelines:

[image]

When the two pipeline are running in parallel some of the Lookup & Copy action are getting hanged and failing after 4:40: (the object & the Pipeline Timeout is set to 7 days - the default value)

[image]

And then both pipelines are failing:

[image]

When I run them one at the time they SOMETIMES managing to complete successfully:

[image]

I suspect that it some kind of loading issue in the Azure Data Factory, the SQL Server or something else, I see the the Log IO are spiking while I'm running the pipelines. How am I supposed to handle this kind of scenario which is classic to any DWH? (i.e. copying from Source System to the Staging area)

Can I time / sync every action? I'd like not to have to build my own orchestration solution.

Comment: You say "when I run them one at [a] time, they SOMETIMES manage to complete successfully". When they fail, when run one at a time, is it the same timeout error?

Comment: Yes, I get the same unrelated Https timeout error

Comment: Short update - there was(and still is) an internal issue with Microsoft infrastructure Azure Data Factory. I'm in touch with their support

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Same problem here, except timing out at almost 20 seconds

Comment: Yeah, I ditched ADF a few months later and started using Talend. Never had reliability issue since :)